# MySQL failing to start on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

There are probably a million other posts with solutions to this but nothing I have tried is working. I have a completely fresh machine running Ubuntu 22.04 and I am trying to install MySQL following [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-22-04) from Digital Ocean. I get to step 3 before things just go wrong, no matter what I do I cannot seem to get MySQL to start.

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xeu mysql.service" for details.
```

This is the output of `systemctl status mysql.service`:

```
× mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2022-07-20 12:16:56 UTC; 6min ago
    Process: 17202 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 4ms

Jul 20 12:16:56 SA-02 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Jul 20 12:16:56 SA-02 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Jul 20 12:16:56 SA-02 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jul 20 12:16:56 SA-02 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 20 12:16:56 SA-02 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

And this is the output of `journalctl -xeu mysql.service`:

```
░░ The job identifier is 7391 and the job result is failed.
Jul 20 12:16:56 SA-02 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 4.
░░ Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ Automatic restarting of the unit mysql.service has been scheduled, as the result for
░░ the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
Jul 20 12:16:56 SA-02 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
░░ Subject: A stop job for unit mysql.service has finished
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ A stop job for unit mysql.service has finished.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 7478 and the job result is done.
Jul 20 12:16:56 SA-02 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
░░ Subject: A start job for unit mysql.service has begun execution
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit mysql.service has begun execution.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 7478.
Jul 20 12:16:56 SA-02 mysql-systemd-start[17202]: MySQL has been frozen to prevent damage to your system. Please see /etc/mysql/FROZEN for help.
Jul 20 12:16:56 SA-02 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
░░ Subject: Unit process exited
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ An ExecStartPre= process belonging to unit mysql.service has exited.
░░ 
░░ The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Jul 20 12:16:56 SA-02 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ The unit mysql.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 20 12:16:56 SA-02 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit mysql.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit mysql.service has finished with a failure.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 7478 and the job result is failed.
Jul 20 12:16:56 SA-02 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
░░ Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ Automatic restarting of the unit mysql.service has been scheduled, as the result for
░░ the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
Jul 20 12:16:56 SA-02 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
░░ Subject: A stop job for unit mysql.service has finished
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ A stop job for unit mysql.service has finished.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 7565 and the job result is done.
Jul 20 12:16:56 SA-02 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jul 20 12:16:56 SA-02 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ The unit mysql.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 20 12:16:56 SA-02 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit mysql.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit mysql.service has finished with a failure.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 7565 and the job result is failed.
```

I am at a complete loss as to what to do to fix this.

Comment: try lowering the number of connections in the config file

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen how would I go about doing that?